# Number of mutually incongruent solutions to $x^2+x \equiv$ 1 mod 101?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked if this has one and only one solution.  The answer key in my text says that it has 0 or 2 mutually incongruent solutions.  How would we know this?  I am not asked to find the solutions, but I see manually that the answers are 22 and 78.

Comment: $x^2+x = x(x+1)$, so if $a(a+1) \cong 1$, then $-a\cdot -(a+1) \cong 1$ is a distinct solution as long as $-a \not \cong a+1$ (so check, from $2a+1 = 101$ that $a = 50$ and $a+1 = 50$ isn't "accidentally" the solution).

Comment: The quadratic formula works here - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

$101$ is prime, so the integers mod $101$ form a field.  A polynomial $P(x)$ over a field has a root $r$ in the field if and only if it is divisible by $x-r$, in which case
the quotient $P(x)/(x-r)$ also divides $P(x)$.  In particular, if $P(x)$ is a monic quadratic and $x-r$ is a root, the quotient is of the form $x-q$ where $q$ is also a root.  The only way $P(x)$ could have only one root in the field is if $q=r$, i.e. $P(x) = (x-r)^2 = x^2 - 2 r x + r^2$.  Now if that was $x^2 + x - 1$, we'd need $-2r \equiv 1 \mod 101$, i.e. $r \equiv 50$, but $50^2 \equiv 76 \mod 101$, not $-1$.  So $x^2 + x - 1$ doesn't have $1$ root in our field; it must be either $0$ or $2$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

$$  4 x^2 + 4x \equiv 4 \pmod{101} $$

$$  4 x^2 + 4x + 1 \equiv 5 \pmod{101} $$

$$  (2x+1)^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{101} $$

Well, $5$ is a quadratic residue, there really is a nonzero $w$   such that $ w^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{101} .$   The two square roots are $\pm w.$   Then solve $2x + 1 \equiv w \pmod{101},$   then    $2x + 1 \equiv -w \pmod{101}$

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).